# Echo user details after login successful

Tags: php, mysql, html

Ehh.. Now its not working?

Now I would like to be able to expand my session echo so I can add username/fullname/etc. if you can show me what I need to do to add a second one, i can figure out how to expand the users values from there.

Trying to echo username, but also be able to expand it onto different pages for username, firstname, last name, emp id, etc...

access.php

```
    <?php
    class Access {      
final public function login( $id, $url = false, $user ) {
        $_SESSION[LOGINSESSION] = $id;

        //you would do this for all columns
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;

        if ( $url )
            new Redirect(urldecode($url));
        else
            new Redirect(URL);
    }

        final public function require_login() {
            if ( ! self::is_logged(true) )
                self::not_logged();
        }
    }
```

index.php

```
    <?php require_once('../admin/pinAPP.php'); $pinAPP = new pinAPP( 'newhire', false, false, true ); ?>
<?php if ( $pinAPP->can_access() ) { ?><!-- New hire -->
    <center>
        <div class="panel">
                    <div>
                        <br>
                            <b><?= $_SESSION['user']['username']; 
//or
$_SESSION['user']['FirstName']; ?>,</b>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                            <p>Below you will find all the necessary information on needed for onboarding process.</p>                  
                        <br> 
                        <br>
                    </div>
<?php } else {} ?>

<!-- -->

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED. You need to set a session variable in the Access::login method to store that information.

```
Access::login(md5($u->username), $_REQUEST['return_url'], $_POST['username']);
```

Pass the username post object to the Access::login method and then set that username inside the method as a session variable:

```
final public function login( $id, $url = false, $username ) {
        $_SESSION[LOGINSESSION] = $id;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        if ( $url )
            new Redirect(urldecode($url));
        else
            new Redirect(URL);
    }
```

Then you will just call a session variable in your pinAPP page:

```
 <?php require_once('../admin/pinAPP.php'); $pinAPP = new pinAPP( 'newhire', false, false, true ); ?>
<?php if ( $pinAPP->can_access() ) { ?><!-- New hire -->
    <center>
        <div class="panel">
                    <div>
                        <br>
                            <b><?= $_SESSION['username']; ?>,</b>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                            <p>Below you will find all the necessary information on needed for onboarding process.</p>                  
                        <br> 
                        <br>
                    </div>
<?php } else {} ?>
```

To pass the entire row to the function:

```
final public function login( $id, $url = false, $user ) {
        $_SESSION[LOGINSESSION] = $id;

        //you would do this for all columns
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;

        if ( $url )
            new Redirect(urldecode($url));
        else
            new Redirect(URL);
    }
```

Then you would change your index page to access the value by:

```
$_SESSION['user']['username']; 
//or
$_SESSION['user']['FirstName'];
```

And you would call the function like this:

```
$userRow = $sql->sqls("UPDATE `". DBPREFIX ."users` SET `last_login_ip` = '". $ip ."', `last_login_timestamp` = '". time() ."' WHERE `username`='$user'");
Access::login(md5($u->username), $_REQUEST['return_url'],$userRow);
```

Comment: Even after your edit, still not working. @JonStevens

Comment: Add a print_r($pinApp); after you instantiate the class and post the result.

Comment: Wait, you haven't declared $username. You need to call something to get the username.

Comment: Not sure where youre referring to that I add "print_r($pinApp);"

Comment: how exactly would I need to declare $username, can you give me an example please? @jon

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object in /index.php on line 32

Comment: Line 32 = "<b><?= $pinApp->getUser(); ?>,</b>"

Comment: $pinAPP not $pinApp. Sorry, my typo.

Comment: Wouldnt I need to do something like  private function getUser() {
     return $this->user;
  $this->user = $sql->sqls("SELECT * FROM `". DBPREFIX ."users` WHERE md5(`username`)='" . $user . "'");
   
 } for my function?

Comment: You are already getting the user in your constructor. Actually, wait, no you aren't. You are trying to but don't have $user declared. I'll edit my code now.

Comment: Still not working, i'll update my OP to show what I have. Maybe I mixed something up?

Comment: Look at my latest edit. How are you going to find the user? You are trying to get the username. So, it's not likely to pass the username to a function that just returns the same username. You will need to find the username some other way and pass that data to the 'getUser()' function. Once you do that with the syntax in my edited code, you will return the final result: "return $user['username'];"

Comment: How exactly would I 'find' the username then pass to the getuser function? Do I need to show you my login page?

Comment: The purpose of the function is to find the username. So, you obviously don't know the username already, or there wouldn't be a point to use a function to find it. What information do you know about the user? THAT is the information you need to pass to the getUser() function to find the user. Also, "someUsername", was just a placeholder, not something to actually put in your code.

Comment: Jon, I have added my model for login and my int file where it matches user after confirming user/pw.. in my OP

Comment: Perfect, so are the users coming from the login modal? If so, you are sending the username in a post request. So, instead of calling a function: $pinAPP->getUser(); just grab the username via the post object: $_POST['username'];

Comment: added my user class as wlel.

Comment: $_post didnt work either.   <b><?= $_POST['username'];?>,</b>

Comment: Where is the user coming from before the index page?

Comment: someurl.com/index.php user is prompted to log in, once user has been logged in successfully their directed to someurl.com/dashboard that is where this index.php rests.

Comment: I have added my access class, i forgot about thats tied to user log in.

Comment: Woops, never mind. It works :) I had to clear my cookies/refresh Firefox. mashing refresh after uploading file changes to FTP can throw you off sometimes ;) Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate your help. Very clear and understanding. - Levi

Comment: Ok great! No problem glad it helped.

Comment: i just tried to change username to whats in the database table "FullName" as column ID like I did with username, and now its not showing. I just want to make sure if i want to add user details other than username like firstname/lastname/employee id/address etc what edits do I need to do? only make the edits in access, and model/login/index session echo?

Comment: Update your question with your latest changes.

Comment: Working... just need to be able to add more than just username for the echo $_SESSION['username']; -- $_SESSION['fullname'];, $_SESSION['empid'];, etc

Comment: Yes, you can add whatever you need as a session variable.

Comment: Because the session is selecting * records where username/password match essentially I can grab any column of data within the users table without changing anything from the access line, or login file? Correct? Or ?

Comment: If you want to return a specific column, you would need to change you select statement in your query.

Comment: change the query in model/login.php  ?

Comment: Right now I have  $u = $sql->sqls("SELECT `id`,`username`, `status`, `is_admin`, `last_login_ip`, `last_login_timestamp` FROM `". DBPREFIX ."users` WHERE `username`='$user' AND `password`='$pass'"); I would add my columns within there correct?

Comment: or make it simple and just SELECT * FROM DBPREFIXusers WHERE username=$user .... etc.

Comment: I added `<?= $_SESSION['FullName']; ?>`, and changed my query to `$u = $sql->sqls("SELECT `id`,`username`, `FullName` `status`, `is_admin`, `last_login_ip`, `last_login_timestamp` FROM `". DBPREFIX ."users` WHERE `username`='$user' AND `password`='$pass'");` and its not displaying the users FullName.

Comment: It will only display the username @jon

Comment: added the FullName to  Access::login(md5($u->username), $_REQUEST['return_url'], $_POST['username'],$_POST['FullName']); and still nothing ?

Comment: When I do your changes for the row, it doesnt work. Give me 1 minute and I'll update what I have on the OP. @jon

Comment: ended up reverting back to the last working version for a temp solution until you get a chance to review my latest attempt. -Thank you again foryour help and I look forward to your response -Levi

Comment: Ended up getting it answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730118/echo-multiple-user-details-values/33730330?noredirect=1#comment55232384_33730330  Again, thank you for your help and your time. I really appreciated it!